# iOS - Obtaining CGRect from cell.textLabel.frame

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, cgrect

I tried to `LogCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame);` but that just gives me `(0, 0) 0 x 0`

How can I find out the CGRect of a textLabel in a cell? Why I'm wondering is because I'm subclassing `UITableViewCell` and I want to keep the dimensions from the original textLabel and subtract the width with 30 pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. At `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the cell's subviews haven't been laid out yet. Use the delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LogCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell`'s textLabel has `CGRectZero` frame by default. You have to set `textLabel.text` to some value for frame to change.

Comment: I've done that but it still doesn't give me the frame: `cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";LogCGRect(cell.textLabel.frame);`

Comment: First, it's `[cell.textLabel setText:@"foo"]`. Second, what's `LogCGRect`? Use `NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel);` instead.

Comment: First, dot notation is OK to use with the modern runtime introduced in Objective-C 2.0. Second, it's a macro for `NSLog`ing `CGRect`s. However, using your recommendations still gives me a `CGRectZero` frame.